# Count Up window.localStorage.getItem via Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I try to could a number in localStorage but the ++ doesnt do it any other way?

```
window.localStorage.setItem('run','++')
```

This is the full code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if(window.localStorage.getItem('run')==null){

        window.localStorage.setItem('run','1')
    }
    else if(window.localStorage.getItem('run')==1){

        window.localStorage.setItem('run','++')
        window.location = "index_aerosoft.html";
    }
    else if(window.localStorage.getItem('run')==25){

        alert("hey 25times");
        window.localStorage.setItem('run','null')
    };
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

`localStorage` only contains strings.

If you want to keep a counter in it, you have to parse it :

```
var c = parseInt(localStorage['run']||'0', 10); // read, with 0 as default value
c++; // increment
localStorage['run'] = c; // store the incremented value
```

Answer (score 1):

The local storage only stored strings. And it cannot parse arguments into expressions to increment a value on the fly, you have to do this manually.

So, you first need to grab the value and parse it to an integer:

```
i = parseInt(window.localStorage.getItem('run'));
```

Then your can store the incremented value:

```
window.localStorage.setItem('run',(i + 1));
```

Note: in your condition

```
else if(window.localStorage.getItem('run')==1){
```

you check if a `1` is stored, I suppose you indent to check if the value is *smaller than 25*? If not, increasing the value is meaningless as the following statement will always be storing 2...

Answer (score 0):

> if(window.localStorage.getItem('run')==null){
>
> ```
>         window.localStorage.setItem('run','1');
>         alert("First start");
>     }else if(window.localStorage.getItem('run')==10){
>
>         window.localStorage.setItem('run','1');
>     }else{
>
>         var run = window.localStorage.getItem('run');
>         var irun;
>         irun = (parseInt(run) + 1);
>         window.localStorage.setItem('run',irun.toString());
>         window.location = "index_xyz.html";
>         alert(window.localStorage.getItem('run'));
>     }
>
> </script>
> ```